# How to cancel a SQL Server reindex rebuild

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using the SQL Server 2008 Maintenance Plan > Rebuild Index, I've scheduled this to run on Sunday at 5:30am against all the databases on server. I'm just concerned that when I go in on Monday that it might still be running.

If that's the case, can anyone advise how it could be cancelled or check how far it need to go before finishing. As it's a live environment, I will need to restore from the backup if it's not finished in time for Monday 8am.

Hardware information: the server is a new Windows 2008 32 bit with a maximum ram installed 4GB. I don't have any more details to hand on the database size etc at the minute as I'm not at work.

Running the rebuild is the equivalent of running this script:

[image]

Kind Regards

James

Comment: Look to see if the maintenance plan job is running and if so stop it. I don't see why you would need to restore from backups just because it didn't finish rebuilding all indexes. You might consider a less blunt approach https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Comment: Hi Martin, I should have explained why I need to run this kind of script. The database is running slower after an upgrade from SQL 2000. Apart from running normal reindexing on a weekly basic, this approach has not been done before which I why I'm a bit anxious. Using this approach, will take the database offline from what I understand which is why I would need to need to make sure I get the users up and running again on Monday morning asap if they cannot log in.

Comment: rebuilding indexes doesn't require taking the DB offline. It will block access to the specific table as you aren't doing an online rebuild but stopping the rebuild should release the table lock quite quickly.

Comment: Hi Martin I'm not at work to check but is there an option within Maintanence Planner to cancel a job? Come to think of, it might be possible from SQL Job Agent as this is where the jobs are created.      I'm reading Brads Mcgehee;s Sure Guide to SQL Server Maintenance Plans but I don't think it says anywhere how to cancel a job - I've also sent him a message on his website but not sure if he will have chance to get back to me before Monday.